# DELETE taking quite a long time, perhaps subquery slow

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables `stage_instance` and `stage_binary` . `stage_binary` has a primary key `id` and `stage_instance` has a normal `int` column called `binary_id`. There is no foreign key constraint in this column , but the column is indexed.

I am issuing this statement for deletion:

```
DELETE FROM stage_instance WHERE binary_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM stage_binary)
```

- `stage_binary` has 240k rows
- `stage_instance` has 130k rows

It takes 19 minutes for the deletion to happen. Is that slow ? How can I make this plan faster ?

Comment: Some info is needed to help you better: What version of Postgresql? What are the specs of the machine where the DB is installed (RAM, processors, clock, is it virtual, etc.)? Do you have any other column indexed?

Comment: check query plan, though i had misgiving whether indexes help much given that `select` do a full table scan anyway. fyi, this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67586737) might be noteworthy for your problem.

Comment: Operating System:  RHEL8
vCPU:  6
Memory:  12
virtual machine
Postgres 14
not sure about clock info...

Comment: does `not exists` help more ? will try

Comment: @DarkCygnus in my question it says i have `binary_id` indexed. the other `id` is a primary key , thus indexed by default

Comment: Is there any other proces active that has a lock on one or more records? Check pg_stat_activity

Comment: I tried this :
`DELETE FROM stage_instance WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * from stage_binary WHERE stage_binary.id = stage_instance.binary_id);`

That runs in 0.14 seconds

Comment: question now is, how can this be much faster ??

Comment: @FrankHeikens checked and everything is idle

Comment: Please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for these statements. (In plain text)

Answer (score 1):

make index of binary_id
run below query make binary_id indexed

```
CREATE INDEX binary_id_index ON stage_instance USING btree(binary_id);
```

Comment: does btree works better ? isnt the default in postgres ? i have that column indexed already

Comment: `CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ix_stage_instance_binary_id
    ON public.stage_instance USING btree
    (binary_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;` I have already